# SQL Query for Test Review

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a databases test next week and I was just going through some of my review questions and I am a little bit stumped by this one if anybody can help me out.

We have four tables:

```
Student(StudentID, Name, Age, Birthday)
Class(ClassName, Department, Time, ProfessorID)
Professors(ProfessorID, Name, Department)
Enrolled(StudentID, ClassName, Score)
```

Here is the question:

```
Find the names of professors for whom the combined enrollment in the
classes they teach is less than 50 students
```

I have a feeling that I am supposed create a view, but the whole less than 50 thing is kind of throwing me off.

Comment: You don't need to create  a view specially. You just need 1. `COUNT`, 2. `JOIN`, 3. `GROUP BY`. three keywords will help you write the required query.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with GROUP BY, but I'll see if I can figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Easy to understand examples - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Much appreciated